# Sending a post request with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

Complete amateur at anything server related and was just trying to send a post request following some of the other answers I found on here but no luck, code crashes at the last line with "Source not found" error.

NOTE: I know that some parameters and headers are missing, do I need to have everything filled out? How can I tell what a proper request looks like?

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

    params.add(new NameValuePair("_sendCopyToSender", "on"));

    params.add(new NameValuePair("adId", "")); 

   params.add(new NameValuePair("bbToken", tok)); 

    params.add(new NameValuePair("bbUserInput", output)); 

    params.add(new NameValuePair("ca.kijiji.xsrf.token", xsrfTok)); 

    params.add(new NameValuePair("emailRequiresVerification", "true"));

    params.add(new NameValuePair("adId", "true"));

    params.add(new NameValuePair("from", emailBox.asText())); 

    params.add(new NameValuePair("fromName", nameBox.asText())); 

    params.add(new NameValuePair("message", message)); 

    requestSettings.setRequestParameters(params);

    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Content-Length", "437");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Host", "www.kijiji.ca");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");              

    Page redirectPage = webClient.getPage(requestSettings); //Crashes here
```

Comment: Do you really like to create the post request yourself? Usually HtmlUnit does all this for your - have a look at https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/gettingStarted.html.

Answer (score 0):

Don't supply the User-Agent ...